# :gt counting from last position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to use something similar to `:gt` selector. I need to select 7 `divs` counting from last position.

```
<nav>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> // to this one
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> // from there
</nav>
```

Is this possible ? Number of elements may change in the upper part of nav.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("nav div").slice(-7);
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 3):

[**`jQuery.slice`**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) can be used with a negative offset:

```
$("nav > div").slice(-7);
```

Answer (score 3):

use **[slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)**

```
$("nav div").slice(-7);
```